# É correto usar «qual» sozinho, sem artigo?

Tags: gramática, pronomes, norma-culta

Às vezes, a palavra não leva artigo, seja por não ter gênero (e.g. *Portugal*), seja por opção (e.g. «Gosto de pessoas»). Aí, não me parecia correto usar o artigo com o pronome relativo *qual*; por exemplo, a frase «Gosto de pessoas, as quais gostam de mim» me soa errado, soando-me mais correto «Gosto de pessoas, quais gostam de mim». Isto é, inclusive, o que falo.

Mas. Então, pergunto. É errado usar o pronome relativo *qual* desacompanhado de artigo?

Comment: O que soa desajeitado para mim é a sua frase: Gosto de pessoas, as quais gostam de mim. Acho que se diria: Gosto das pessoas que gostam de mim. "Fosse qual fosse a solução"....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não. O correto é "[...], as quais gostam de mim". Os únicos pronomes relativos que não necessitam do artigo são: cujo (e suas flexões), que, quem, quanto (e suas flexões) onde, como e quando.

De acordo com Evanildo Bechara:

> *"usa-se **o qual** (e flexões) em lugar de **que**, principalmente quando o relativo se acha afastado do seu antecedente e o uso deste último possa dar margem a mais de uma interpretação:*
>
> *O guia da turma, **o qual** nos veio visitar hoje, prometeu-nos voltar depois."*

Fernando Pestana, também explica que *"o [pronome] relativo que só deve ser antecedido de preposição monossilábica (“a, com, de, em, por; exceto sem e sob”). Do contrário, usam-se os variáveis “o qual, os quais, a qual, as quais” (sem restrição quanto ao uso das preposições ou locuções prepositivas)."*

O artigo serve também para evitar ambiguidade.

*Gosto de pessoas, quais [pessoas] gostam de mim?*
*Gosto de pessoas, as quais [que] gostam de mim?*